# Can't access prestashop admin portal after updating to 1.7.4

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I recently updated from prestashop 1.7.2 to 1.7.4 and now am getting an HTTP error 500 when trying to access the admin portal. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Same problem... anyone fixed it?

Comment: activate debug mode from your host control panel to see what the error is. go to root/config/defines.inc.php and change false to true in: "define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false)".